# Why Devi Para-Shakti is not shown with three eyes in many parts of India?

Tags: puranas, gods, tantra

The dhyana mantras of Devi Para-Shakti in different Tantras and Puranas of forms like Durga, Kaali etc describe Devi as three-eyed. But most deities of Devi or even of Shiva outside bengal show Her (or Him) with two eyes! What is the reason of this?

Comment: Usually the third eye is shown only in the ugra-swaroopa. Narasimha is also supposed to have three eyes in his ugra-swaroopa when he killed Hiranyakashipu, and only those temples depicting the scene show the third eye. So maybe those shiva / kali temples which show the ugra-swaroopa scene will depict the third eye. Note that, in the south, usually the traditional (usually older) temples of Shiva only have him in the linga form.

Comment: @user1952500 No they have nothing to do with ugra rupa as Jagaddhatri and Annapurna are also shown with three eyes.Only if a different dhyana-mantra is found, two eyes can be scceptable:)

Comment: i saw, a devi's dhyana , which has "trinetram", but without ugra-swaroopa!!!

Comment: @SaMolPP yes ugra-rupa has nothing to do with it